# Add string to int / Add ints in form of String

Tags: android, string, colors, int, addition

I need to know how to add strings in the form of an integer so for example if I need to use `setBackgroudColor(int)` it can be like so :

```
 String a = "15"; // Here I mean like its user changeable , so the user can change only this part of the int;
 View.setBackgroundColor("0x" + a + "000000");
```

To clarify more , I want these two digits to be user changeable , and still here is an example :

```
1 + 1 = 2 // which is I don't want

1 + 1 = 11 // which I want
```

Please help me in this case , if you need anything more please tell me ...

Comment: so you are wanting concatenation, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the above answers should do the trick, for your case you might look into the `Color.argb()` method. Not sure how you're getting user input, but let's just assume they're `EditText` objects:

```
EditText a, r, g, b;
//initialize them

int aInt, rInt, gInt, bInt;

try {
    aInt = Integer.valueOf(a.getText().toString());
    bInt = Integer.valueOf(b.getText().toString());
    cInt = Integer.valueOf(c.getText().toString());
    dInt = Integer.valueOf(d.getText().toString());
} catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    //Throw a warning dialog that the user's input was invalid
}

view.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(aInt, rInt, gInt, bInt));
```

This is of course assuming you're getting input in the form of integers 0-255.

EDIT: Actually, if you're just wanting to change the alpha part of it, it's much easier. You could just get the input from the user as an integer from 0-255, validate it, and do this:

```
EditText alpha;
String alphaString;

try {
    alphaString = Integer.toHexString(alpha.getText().toString());
} catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    //Throw warning
}

view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#" + alphaString + "000000"));
```

Comment: Thank you ! Best answer till now ! Just what I need !

Answer (score 1):

You can do this directly in binary math. To set ARGB, you could use the following logic:

```
int a = 0x10;
int r = 0x20;
int g = 0x30;
int b = 0x40;

int finalColor = (a << 24) + (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b;
```

Typing 0x (that's the number zero and the letter "X") means the number is in hexadecimal format. This means you could say this:

```
int red = 0xff; // This is valid.
```

The logic I gave you allows you to specify colours in hex, and get the int value of your color.

The operation "<<" is a "binary shift", and it shifts your bits into the correct location.

For example:

```
int x = 1;
x = x << 1;
// Now x is equal to 2 (since 1 shifted to the left is 10, which is 2 in binary).
```

The code I gave you above shifts all the colours properly.

Try out that logic in your code :)

I'm available if you have any more questions.

Comment: I have never heard about whatever you said , anyway isn't 0x10 = 0 , 0x20 = 0 ?? Could u explain it a bit or link me somewhere please ?

Comment: Sure. Expanding my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation , however i still don't understand the shifting much , I can work my stuff now , but I still don't get the shifting and binary thing ...